# Difference between specifying a view as isRoot() & withId

Tags: android, kotlin, user-interface, testing, android-espresso

I want to know the difference in specifying a view in different ways

onView(withId(R.id.btnAuthLogin)).perform(click());

onView(isRoot()).perform(waitId(R.id.btnAuthLogin, 1000));

**It's not the delay thing that i want to know**

What happens when we specify isRoot() rather than specifying withID.

Hope there is no confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`isRoot()` returns the root view of your layout, such as the constraint or relative layout hosting your views.

`withId()` returns the view with a matching ID from the layout, or throws an error showing the structure of your view hierarchy

You set a views Id in XML using `android:id="@+id/your_id_here"`